# VB.Net Color Variation like in Autoit

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple pixelsearch function searching for a certain Argb Color on screen.
This already works great and it finds the pixel with the color but I would like to add a Color Variation detection to it.

The Color of the pixel it should detect changes sometimes from (255, 100, 100, 100) to (255, 110, 94, 102) or something else (values are changing 10 points). Now the Pixelsearch function should have a Variationdetection so it would detect pixels with a near similar color so instead of only searching for color (255, 100, 100, 100) it should also search for (255, 101, 99, 102)... and more.

Is it possible to code that instead of Dim each Color and search for it?

Thats the code that I have already:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim xd3 = Color.FromArgb(255, 100, 100, 100) 'Searching for this color on the screen

    Dim b As New Bitmap(2210, 1100)  'Position of Bitmap
    Dim g As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(b)
    g.CopyFromScreen(Me.Left, Me.Top, 0, 0, b.Size) 'Searching on Screen

    For i = 0 To (Me.Width - 0) 'searching each pixel
        For j = 0 To (Me.Height - 0) 'searching each pixel
            If b.GetPixel(i, j) = xd3 Then 'If pixel has same color that im searching for it will show a messagebox true
                MessageBox.Show("true")
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest something like this :

```
If Color_Is_In_The_Target_Variations(10, b.GetPixel(i, j), xd3) Then
    MessageBox.Show("true")
End If
```

and

```
Private Function Color_Is_In_The_Target_Variations(variation As Integer, tested As Color, target As Color) As Boolean

    If tested.R >= target.R - variation And tested.R <= target.R + variation And
    tested.G >= target.G - variation And tested.G <= target.G + variation And
    tested.B >= target.B - variation And tested.B <= target.B + variation Then

        Return True
    Else
        Return False

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thank you very much it works perfect :)

Comment: It was a pleasure :)